# Directed tree decompositions on subtrees of DAGs

Tags: graph-theory, tree, directed-acyclic-graph, treewidth

Given a DAG, is the arboreal decomposition of the DAG with the guarantee that given a node $x$, $v$ such that $x$ is reachable from $v$ are in the subtree of $x$? If not, is there a similar decomposition that achieves this?